# Rigging a ball type character for a game

Tags: animation, rigging, unity

I built a very simple character that will be used in a game i am trying out. What is the best way to rig this so that it is playable in Unity? Below is a list of what I am trying to achieve.

1. The base of the ball needs to move in all directions. Forwards, backwards, left and right.
2. The Head needs to rotate left and right
3. The Canons Up and Down.
   [image: Ball Character]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is playable in unity, but I'll give it a shot anyways.

I would recommend using basic keyboard controls for the main movement, and mouse-look for both the cannons and the head.

Here are the settings for the body movement.
[image]

Also, if you want the head to stay with the body, parent it to the body, and the cannons to the head.

Here are the settings for rotating the head.
[image]

If the head's rotation isn't working, click on the "Use X axis" button and click on the "Use Y axis" to disable the incorrect rotation.

Use the same settings for the cannons, but inverted (Click on the "Use X/Y axis" until the settings are opposite of the head settings).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try this out sometime using the game engine in blender.